# How to access a form's id or style if it contains accordingly named inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In this example

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="style">
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <input type="text" name="id">
</form>
```

you cannot access form1's style declaration or form2's id, since the named inputs shadow the corresponding properties.

[The same holds for other properties too](http://jsfiddle.net/6d8sx/)

Any workarounds?

**Edit:**
`getAttribute` works for `id`, obviously. But not for `style`, `childNodes`, `tagName` etc.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
getDomProp = (function() {
    if (window.__lookupGetter__) {
        var cleanForm = document.createElement('form');
        return function(form, key) {
            // works in Firefox, fails in Opera:
            return cleanForm.__lookupGetter__(key).call(form);
        };
    } else if (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor) {
        return function(form, key) {
            // does not work at all:
            // return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(cleanForm, key).get.call(form);
        }
    } else {
        throw 'Not supported.';
    }
})();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pTcK/)

Comment: realistically you really shouldn't name your elements reserved keywords.

Comment: What are you trying to crash?

Comment: @Joseph: Those are not [reserved keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words).

Comment: @Pumbaa80 for javascript, yes; but they are keywords for HTML. And in any case you're missing the point.  You simply shouldn't do it.

Comment: @Joseph Well, they're not keywords, but just predefined names for attributes. And they're also not reserved.

Comment: As an additional piece of information: I didn't manually write a form like that, just to find out it blocks the DOM calls. I'm talking about generated forms, user scripts etc. where the JS developer has no control over the HTML.

Comment: @Pumba `getAttribute` works for `style` - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/aZJS8/ - It doesn't work for `childNodes` and `tagName` because those two are not HTML attributes, but DOM properties...

Comment: @Pumbaa80: It works for style. If you check the fiddle in my answer, you'll see it working.

Comment: `getAttribute('style')` returns a string, `form.style` [should return a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-ElementCSSInlineStyle). This is a huge difference.

Answer (score 2):

This will still work:

```
form.getAttribute('id');
```

PS. Don't name your inputs that in production code :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `getAttribute` to get the corresponding form attributes: http://jsfiddle.net/6d8sx/3/

```
alert('id: ' + form.getAttribute('id'));
```

**Edit:** `getAttribute` seems to work in IE9, FF5 (not sure about others).

However, naming your elements that way will cause problems down the line (if not your code, then some library or plugin might get confused).

Comment: Also, `getPropertyValue` is something different. It's used on CSS style declaration objects to retrieve individual property values, and it's not supported in IE at all. So, `getPropertyValue` is **not** a replacement for `getAttribute`.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Yeah, also `getAttribute` seems to work in FF5, IE9 (don't have Chrome/Safari) but I guess it'll work there too. Edited my answer.

Comment: The `getAttribute` method is part of the DOM Core standard since its inception in the 90's - [see here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-745549614). Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera support this method from the start, ergo, there does not exist a single version of these browsers that doesn't support it. The only issue is (and has always been) with IE, since IE didn't support DOM standards until recent.

Comment: I have friends that weren't yet born at the time when `getAttribute` was standardized - it's that old! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Access them using `.getAttribute();` 
http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/getAttribute

Answer (score -2):

yuse jquery: `$('#form1').css()`, or `$('#form2').attr('id')`.